# Chrome prerendering feature causes problems to interactive pages

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, websocket

For the newer Google chrome browsers, i.e. version 17+ (not sure if other browsers do this too), it seems that by default a pre-rendering feature (see http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1385029) is enabled, which means that a page is being loaded even before the user finishes typing the url in the address bar!

I guess this is a fine trick for pages with mostly static contents, which deceives the users to make the page load faster by effectively loading it earlier. However, this is problematic for pages which triggers some action/logic upon loading.

For example, consider a page which establishes a `websocket` connection to the server and sends a msg as soon as it is loaded. While the user is typing the url for this page, the connection may well already be made and msg is sent, but when the user actually presses 'enter' in the address bar, the `websocket` connection is lost and re-established again, and the msg is re-sent, probably because websocket treats the actual page load as a refresh. Now, if you have some logic that responds to disconnection or receiving certain msgs, this may cause confusing behaviors at the server-end. Another example may be redirections, in which case a double redirection may happen because the page is effectively loaded twice.

Is there any effective way to deal with this browser feature, apart from turning it off which is something that is out of developers' control? Some `JavaScript` tricks?

Comment: Can you verify that this is true? It seems to me that this is something people from Google would take care of.

Comment: @bellpeace, at least based on my experience, which I've just discovered by watching my server log side-by-side with the browser while I start typing the url, this is true...

Comment: I am pretty sure that you will see something in the log since the request for the resources are happening. However, I am not sure about JavaScript execution. What if I have `alert("Hello!")` in an inline script? Will that rise an alert box while I am typing (before I pressed enter)?

Comment: @bellpeace, well, not just the requests I see in the log, but the actual websocket connection is made and a msg is sent across. All these happen even before I press 'Enter' and browser renders the actual page. How about that for JavaScript execution? I am on the latest Chrome btw.

Comment: @bellpeace - can confirm this is true.  We have the same problem (also WS). IMO this is a poorly designed feature of chrome.

Answer (score 1):

See
https://developers.google.com/chrome/whitepapers/pagevisibility

Use document.webkitVisibilityState  to check if it's "prerender" state.
Don't connect websocket if it's "prerender" state.

Hope this helps.
Cheer!

Comment: The `document.webkitVisibilityState == 'prerender'` can be used to detect this, but it's not as simple as just not connecting in these cases, as e.g. it happpens as they are typing.  If you fail to connect then the app won't work.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, I ran into this problem and used the visibility state to skip socket connection but as of 51.0.2704.103, suddenly my page started just rendering white on first load. Turns out they fixed it so that the pre-render persists your web socket connection over to the rendered page, but it doesn't re-run your code; so, if you leave that code you'll end up with no web sockets or weird errors, or a white page. Kind of a mess, but for now I took the pre-render check back out and it seems to be working again.